# StatusBar Hidden Issue in IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift

I am having one issue using status bar. I am using stroyboard id to navigate from `oneviewcontroller` to `secondViewcontroller`. I want to hide second Viewcontroller Status bar, but its not hiding and `OneViewcontroller` has status bar not hidden. I am using iOS 9 , Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if statusBarIsVisible {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do what you want is to explicitly set the status bar (per @Umair's answer) for **each and every** view controller. Take out the if statement you have - just return true if you want it, false if you don't. It's three lines of code per view controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your secondViewController add this method

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This will hide status bar on secondViewController

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Info.plist file

2.Hover on one of those lines and a (+) and (-) button will show up.

3.Click the plus button to add new key Type in start with capital V and automatically the first choice will be View controller-based status bar appearance.

4.Add that as the KEY.
Set the VALUE to "NO"

5.Go to you AppDelegate.swift
Add the code, inside the method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarHidden = true
    return true
}
```